# Why can electrolytes be used as an insulator?

Tags: voltage

Why can electrolytes be used as insulators? Is it because the ions are very stable atoms and will never ever gain, loss or share atoms with something else?

An example is the electrolyte battery:
[image]

Comment: Let me turn this question around for a minute: what makes you think that the electrolyte acts as an insulator?

Comment: @duskwuff because electrons cannot pass through it, I guess :)

Comment: @asd: For a material to be an electric isolator not only electrons may not pass through it but **any** charged particles may not pass through it. Ions **are** charged particles. As a result also electrons (whose excess or lack make the ions charged) can travell through an electrolyte.

Comment: No electrons pass through humans.  Therefore human bodies are insulators, and we cannot get electrocuted, or even slightly zapped!  Right?  Nope.  Currents in salt water are flows of +Na and -Cl ions.  And in car batteries, the acid is a proton-conductor.  (Acids are conductive because of high mobility "free" protons.  search Grotthuss Mechanism, the "hopping protons" effect.)

Comment: An electrolyte is a conductor of electricity. Because it conducts electricity in means of ions (Ionic conduction). This is in contrast to a metallic conductor in which conduction is in means of electrons. Insulator is something that does not conduct electricity in means of electrons or ions.  So an electrolyte is not an insulator.

Answer (score 3):

They generally can't.

In an electrolytic capacitor, the  electrolyte conducts pretty well (look at the ESR of the capacitor). But it electrolytically oxidises a layer on the aluminium anode, and that oxide layer is the insulator.

I'll let someone else explain about batteries.

Answer (score 3):

An electrolyte is a liquid that contains ions (by definition) so it is always a conductor. Salt water is an electrolyte and conducts reasonably well. Deionized water is not, and is a poor conductor (in fact we use the resistivity to specify the purity sometimes).

A dielectric liquid such as oil is not a conductor.

In Brian's example of the electrolytic capacitor, the actual dielectric (insulator) is the ultra-thin aluminum oxide on each plate, and the eponymous electrolyte is the **conductor** which allows the plates to be physically separated yet electrically connected despite the separator and nooks and crannies in each (etched) plate.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the answer with regard to batteries...

The electrolyte is most definitely not an insulator. The reason that electrons don't flow and short out the cell internally is that the reactions occurring between the electrolyte and the anode and cathode create potential barriers that the electrons can't cross. The only path available to them is through the external circuit.

Comment: Thank you (to all), but I would like to look more into that chemical reaction then. I have read [electrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis) and some other articles, but I do not think that I have encountered something about the "potential barriers". Do you have a source that you could recommend me?

Comment: You could start by checking out [questions tagged "electrochemistry" on Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrochemistry)...

Comment: Well, but I still have a hard time finding information about the chemical reaction that makes this potential barrier :( Is the process called something specific? It is not because I am lazy, just not sure what to search for.

Comment: All of them. Whenever a redox reaction occurs, it's because there's a net drop in energy when an electron passes from one reagent to another. The voltage associated with this depends very much on the specific reagents involved. Start reading, and you should soon see a pattern developing.